# How to manage socket in client side as ejs template and react js and the server side it is nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

In my project use the reactJS for frontend and ejs template engine with a node for the backend. already the project is started so now I can't change the whole project into reactJS.

creating one chat app with two clients(react and ejs) and one server(nodeJs) but I stuck in message passing to both clients at one time.

my code is below please tell me is that possible to create a chat app with ejs, node, and react.

ejs:-

```
<script src="/backend/chat/socketMessage.js"></script>
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
socket.on('receive-user',function(data){
    console.log('receive on ejs');
})
```

reactJs:-

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
    const ENDPOINT = 'localhost:8080';
    constructor() {
    super();
    endpoint:ENDPOINT,
    }
    const {endpoint} = this.state;
    const socket = io(endpoint);
    socket.on('receive-user', this._messageRecieve);

    _messageRecieve(message) {
        console.log(message)
    }
```

nodeJS:-

```
module.exports = function(io) {
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
        socket.emit('receive-user',details);
    })
}
```

Please Help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use as per below it will work fine

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
   io.sockets.emit('receive-user',details);
})
```